# Return an array of object in a ionic reactjs component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-react

I have this component that is called in my main file, this component displays all the data, the data returns an array

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
        IonRow,
        IonCol
    } from '@ionic/react';
    
    import data from '../data/data.json';
    
    const BookList: React.FC = () => {
        
        return(
            data.data.map((context) => {
            <IonRow>
                <IonCol size="9">
                    <p>{context.name}</p>
                </IonCol>
                <IonCol size="3">
                    <p>{context.payload}</p>
                </IonCol>
            </IonRow>
            })
        );
        
    };
    
    export default BookList;
```

And the error is like:

[image: error]

somewhere in declaring booklist. Im new to react so its kinda bit hard to understand what the main problem is, I tried to search for any solutions but cant find definite and clear solution that I understand.

Comment: Try removing { } from map

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi when I tried to remove it, error something like this Type '() => JSX.Element[]' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
  Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was returning an array of elements, see this
`Type '() => JSX.Element[]' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'`, all you need is to return a single element using `<div>` or react fragment i.e. <> </>

Try this:

```
const BookList: React.FC = () => (       
  <>
    {data.data.map(({ name, payload }) => (
      <IonRow>
           <IonCol size="9">
               <p>{name}</p>
           </IonCol>
           <IonCol size="3">
               <p>{payload}</p>
           </IonCol>
       </IonRow>
    ))}
  </>
);
```

Comment: After applying the answer, error show something like this
Type '() => JSX.Element[]' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
  Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key

Comment: try wrapping the return value in react fragment, check the updated answer

Comment: does creating component is correct @heisaif? the error appears on the declaration of function component

Comment: If you can create an example in stackblitz I can take a look.

Comment: Im currently creating stackblitz,  still waiting to finish installing dependencies

Comment: It solves the problem, can you mind to share what the cause of that problem?

Comment: Your code was returning an array of elements, see this `Type '() => JSX.Element[]' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'`, all you need is to return a single element using `<div>` or react fragment i.e. `<> </>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216382/discussion-between-nyx97-and-heisaif).